# PHP- insert innerhtml with javascript dynamically in each row of table

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom, innerhtml

InnerHtml not working in this case, i want to do something like this:

```html
  <table width="100%" border="0" id="table2">
    
    <?php
     include("connection.php");
  $sql=mysql_query("select* from b1");
  while($res=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
  {
 $img=$res["img"];
 $url=$res["url"];
   ?>
    <tr>
      <td><script>document.body.innerHTML="<a href='"+<?php echo '$url' ; ?>.value+"'><img src='"+<?php echo '$img' ; ?>+"' / ></a>" ;</script></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
  }
  ?>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just do this?

```html
  <table width="100%" border="0" id="table2">
    
    <?php
     include("connection.php");
  $sql=mysql_query("select* from b1");
  while($res=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
  {
 $img=$res["img"];
 $url=$res["url"];
   ?>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="<?php echo $url ; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $img; ?>" / ></a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
  }
  ?>
  </table>
```

Comment: i agree with this solution - but don't forget to add ALT text and width / height properties to the images, also mysql_query is old and now deprecated - try PDO or mysqli